# SQL trigger on update or delete

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have to have one single trigger that fires on either the UPDATE OR DELETE operations.  I have the trigger working fine for when one certain column is updated.  However, I need different logic for when a DELETE operation was fired.  How would I have both logic inside of one trigger?  Here is what I have so far:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Audit_Emp_Trigger]
   ON  [dbo].[EMPLOYEE]
   AFTER UPDATE, DELETE
AS 

BEGIN
    --Only execute the trigger if the Dno field was updated or deleted
    IF UPDATE(Dno)
    BEGIN

    --If the Audit_Emp_Record table does not exist already, we need to create it
    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Audit_Emp_Record') IS NULL
    BEGIN
    --Table does not exist in database, so create table
    CREATE TABLE Audit_Emp_Record
    (
    date_of_change smalldatetime,
    old_Lname varchar (50),
    new_Lname varchar (50),
    old_ssn int,
    new_ssn int,
    old_dno int,
    new_dno int
    );

    --Once table is created, insert the values of the update operation into the table
    INSERT INTO Audit_Emp_Record(date_of_change, old_Lname, new_Lname, old_ssn, new_ssn, old_dno, new_dno) SELECT GETDATE(), D.Lname, I.Lname, D.Ssn, I.Ssn, D.Dno, I.Dno FROM inserted I JOIN deleted D ON I.Ssn = D.Ssn

    END

    ELSE
    BEGIN
    --The table already exists, so simply insert the new values of the update operation into the table
    INSERT INTO Audit_Emp_Record(date_of_change, old_Lname, new_Lname, old_ssn, new_ssn, old_dno, new_dno) SELECT GETDATE(), D.Lname, I.Lname, D.Ssn, I.Ssn, D.Dno, I.Dno FROM inserted I JOIN deleted D ON I.Ssn = D.Ssn
    END

    END

END
```

Comment: If the logic is so different between `UPDATE` and `DELETE` - why not just have two separate triggers, each focused on their one operation??

Comment: @marc_s : comments related to my answer revealed that the logic wasn't that different at all. Both operations are logging the data to the same audit table; the `UPDATE` joins the `INSERTED` and DELETED` tables while the `DELETE` just pulls from the `DELETED` table. Just FYI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can test for the type of operation by seeing which of the magic-/pseudo-tables -- `INSERTED` and `DELETED` have data in them.  I prefer to use something like the following:

```
DECLARE @Operation CHAR(1);

IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted))
BEGIN

   IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted))
   BEGIN
      -- rows in both has to be an UPDATE
      SET @Operation = 'U';
   END;
   ELSE
   BEGIN
      -- no rows in "deleted" has to be an INSERT
      SET @Operation = 'I';
   END;

END;
ELSE
BEGIN
   -- no rows in "inserted" has to be a DELETE
   SET @Operation = 'D';
END;
```

You can then use the `@Operation` variable in an IF statement to do one or the other of those operations.

Something like:

```
IF (@Operation = 'U')
BEGIN

    --Only execute the trigger if the Dno field was updated or deleted
    IF UPDATE(Dno)
    BEGIN
       {your current code here}
    END;
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
    {what to do if the operation is a DELETE goes here}
END;
```

Technically you don't need the `ELSE` condition that sets `@Operation = 'I';`, but if you are going to copy/paste this code into various triggers or keep around as a template then no harm in it handling all three conditions.

Also, just as a side-note, you don't need the `ELSE` condition of the `IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Audit_Emp_Record') IS NULL` statement, nor the `INSERT INTO Audit_Emp_Record` that is just after the `CREATE TABLE` but before the `END`. Just do the `CREATE TABLE` if it doesn't exist and then do the `INSERT` outside of that test. Meaning:

```
IF UPDATE(Dno)
BEGIN
    --If the Audit_Emp_Record table does not exist already, we need to create it
    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Audit_Emp_Record') IS NULL
    BEGIN
       --Table does not exist in database, so create table
       CREATE TABLE Audit_Emp_Record
       ...
    END

    INSERT INTO Audit_Emp_Record(...)
END
```

Comment: I could not do an ELSE because I only want to execute the block of code in the IF UPDATE(Dno) if the Dno column is updated, not for any other columns

Comment: @JonathanDurda: ah, good point. I guess I can remove that part of my answer then. It was just something that popped in my head.  But the first part still stands.

Comment: Thank you for the solution.  My only other question is, am I able to tell which column was deleted by scanning the deleted table?  For example, I want to only execute code inside of the DELETE block if the Dno column was delted.

Comment: @JonathanDurda: I just updated again with a suggestion to simplify the code without changing the logic.  But as to your question here about which column was deleted, all of them ;-). You cannot delete columns; you only delete rows.

Comment: Thank you!  So to clarify, if I was recording changes into the Audit_Emp_Record, I can record old and new values for an UPDATE statement, but for a DELETE statement, it would make sense to just insert NULL for each column correct?

Comment: @JonathanDurda : Correct, if you mean that you will use `NULL` for each of the "new" fields. There will only be data in the `DELETED` table as there is nothing `INSERTED` or "new" ;-).